# Refresh listview on android

Tags: android, listview, refresh, resume

in my project I need to refresh the listview after some changes.
I use the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  this.onCreate(null);
}
```

When I run the project, the logcat returns this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {it.xxx.yyy/it.xxx.yyy.TabsActivity}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do on this this.onCreate(null);

Comment: searching around the web i've found that this is the stack to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call onCreate method in onPause. Its affect to Android lifecycle.

You must to do:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To force an update (where adapter must be tour adapter variable)

Comment: Instead of this.onCreate(null);

Comment: android studio hasn't the command "notifiyDataSetChanged()" for my ListAdapter.

Comment: Where is the type of your adapter?

Comment: I create a variable ListAdapter adapter as a global variable.
Inside onCreate(...) I write: adapter = new SimpleAdapter( blablabla)
myListView.setAdapter(adapter); that's it

Comment: Check your code, simpleadapter have a notifyDataSetChanged() method inherit from BaseAdapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: but I have to create it as "SimpleAdapter myAdapter" instead "ListAdapter myAdapter"... right?

Comment: nothing to do... it doesn't work. onResume(){super.onResume(); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is just to refresh the List View,  you can just call the below adapter method in. This would refresh the list view and of course you need to update the List with the changed values before calling this.

```
 @Override
 protected void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. On debug i can go inside onResume() but nothing happens